# BLE Universal sample app not working on windows 10 (IBM Lenovo Thinkpad L560)

Tags: winapi, bluetooth-lowenergy, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

I've used the windows universal apps found [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples) to test the bluetooth low energy feature with a windows 10 (64bit) laptop. But I noticed that the same app doesn't work on certain laptops while working on certain other applications.

For example the BLE app worked correctly on a hp probook 450 G2 where it listened to heart rate monitoring BLE beacons. But the same app didn't receive any packets from the same beacon in another ibm lenovo thinkpad L560. (Both same OS, 64 bit)

This is the screenshot of a working app on the hp laptop.
[image]

This is the same app not-working on the ibm laptop
[image]

***EDIT:***
Both laptops shows bluetooth low energy support in the device manager.
[image]

Is this a known behavior? Has anyone already seen this kind of behavior?

(I can see few threads on windows mobile, but this is on windows laptops)

Answer (score 0):

Bluetooth LE, AKA Bluetooth 4.0, BLE and Bluetooth Smart is supported by most Operating Systems on mobile tablet and desktop,
 but the device needs a dedicated chip.

The hp Probook 450 G2 has Bluetooth 4.0 .

The IBM Thinkpad(latest model is from 2005) certainly has not.

Check the windows device manager to  see if Bluetooth devices have BLE capability(Bluetooth 4.0 or higher).

Comment: I'm sorry for the miscommunication. But the "Not-Working" laptop is IBM Lenovo thinkpad L560 which is found in the below link. According to that link the laptop has Bluetooth 4.1 support. I'll edit the question.
http://www3.lenovo.com/gb/en/laptops/thinkpad/l-series/L560/p/22TP2TBL560